visual studio code + react+ vite - debug chrome extension as typescript
I am quite new to react. I created chrome extension with react, using vite. I read a lot of articles, and I can not start debuginng typescript contect scripts. If content script is defines as .js file, then it works fine. If I add this script, as typescript (ex. content.ts) after breaking into, or writting debugger some temporary file content.js is opened where vs is debugging. If try to debug some code from .ts file (not content script) then it is ok. I do not know how to achieve to debug content script defined as .ts file.
my lunch.json
     {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Extension",
          "url": "https://www.onet.pl/",
          // Here it is!
          "runtimeArgs": [
            "--load-extension=${workspaceFolder}/build/",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
          ],
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        }

vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: "public/manifest.json",
          dest: ".",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
    sourcemap: true, // Upewnij się, że sourcemap jest włączony
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: "./index.html", // Główna aplikacja
        content: "./src/content.ts", //
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: "assets/[name].js", // Nazwa pliku wyjściowego
        manualChunks: undefined, // Wyłączenie dzielenia kodu
      },
    },
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
  },
});

any help

Use sourcemap: 'inline'

great, it works !

also found another solution. Add
"web_accessible_resources": [
{
"resources": ["assets/*"],
"matches": ["<all_urls>"]
}
to manifest.json
